# Jquery Mobile list in collapsible onclick event doesn't work when dynamically added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Can someone please tell me why this: [JSfiddle static added collapsible and list](http://jsfiddle.net/robsy/s5j3w7j4/)  is working and this: [JSfiddle "dynamically" added collapsible and list](http://jsfiddle.net/robsy/gLrneutt/) isn't working?

Of course this are only examples. But I think if the click event in the second JSFiddle-project is working I'll also be able to fix this in my project.

It also would be nice if I can trigger only one click Event with both ul's but this is not so important for now:

```
    $("#test1 & 2").on("click", 'li', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: both jsfiddle links are working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need this:

```
$("#createmangelpagecollapsible").on("click", 'li', function() {
      alert($(this).text());
});
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gLrneutt/3/)

As `#test1` and `#test2` `ul`s are also genrated on the fly so you can't have it as a closest parent element as a selector, the other side you're appending `ul` to `#createmangelpagecollapsible` div so use it as a closest parent element(container).

Comment: Thank you very much!! i searched for this so long..